# react native IOS foreground , can't receive push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I'm using react native push notifications with firebase messaging to handle notifications in my Application.

I installed libraries and i make config :

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions the i added :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
  // [START configure_firebase]
  [FIRApp configure];
  // [END configure_firebase]

  // [START set_messaging_delegate]
  [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
  // [END set_messaging_delegate]

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"eXpanded"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // ####################################
  if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
  // iOS 10 or later
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
  UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
      UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
      requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // ...
      }];
  } else {
    // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  }

  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
  // ####################################

   // Define UNUserNotificationCenter
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

  return YES;
}
```

I added code to willPresentNotification :

```
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

  // Print message ID.
  if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
  }

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

  // Change this to your preferred presentation option
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
}
```

Notifications works only in the background but i can't receive notifications when app is launched (foreground)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, notification won't show up if your app is foreground. But there's a listener you can try to work with

`firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => { // your handling goes here })`

You can check for more https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage